# How to change DNS IP for programmatically on CF 2.0

Tags: compact-framework, dns

I want to change the DNS IP Address programmatically to the Adapter on Compact Framework. I have checked in the NetworkInterface class of OpenNetCF 2.3 as well, but I do not want the device to be rebooted after setting.

Could somebody throw a light on the please?

Answer (score 1):

The adapter's DNS server addresses are stored in the registry in a key like this:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\<Adapter Name>\Parms\Tcpip]`
`"DNS"=REG_MULTI_SZ:<IP address of the DNS name server>.`

Note that it is a **multi_sz** value.

Simply update the registry and rebind the adapter using the SDF's `NetworkInterface.Rebind()` method or by calling `DeviceIoControl` on the NDIS device with `IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER` (which is what the SDF's call is doing).